# Rising DC Voltage

Tags: gpio, altium, cad

I only have 3.3 DC Voltage on the pin of PCB and I want to supply a chip 5V. What are the ways to manage this?

PS: The voltage on the pin is always 3.3 V and max current on it can be 50 mA.

Comment: I think that this can help you http://cdn.instructables.com/FGB/UJLG/HJKBJU9F/FGBUJLGHJKBJU9F.LARGE.jpg. You just need to choose correct Rb resistor and transistor for your needs.

Comment: Doesnt it still need a higher voltage on the side of collector?

Comment: Are you providing power to the chip that needs 5Volts or are you just sending it a signal?

Comment: I need to do both of them but the chip needs to have 5V on one of its pins

Comment: You need 5v power supply ofc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boost converter: -

[image]

OR

[image]

OR

[image]

Try searching for "boost converter 3V3 to 5V"

Answer (score 0):

As @Andy aka says, you will need a boost converter to get 5Volts from the 3.3V that you have.

You say you also need to send that 5Volt chip a signal, so you may also need the level shifter as mentioned by Sada93.

Whether you need the level shifter or not depends on the chip that you are using.  Some chips that run on 5V can also accept 3.3V logic levels, but many can't.

It also depends on whatever is generating the 3.3V signal - it may not like having an output connected to an input that could float up to 5Volts.

There are tricks that you can use that may make the level converter simpler (just a diode and a resistor, for example,) but that depends on what the signal does and how fast it has to switch and what voltage levels  will be detected as high/low.

---

After posting, I see that the answer from Sada93 has been deleted.  [See this related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127606/simplest-uni-directional-level-shifter-3-3v-5v) for info on level shifting.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look to the datasheet of the chip again.