# Implementing Modbus RTU on a UART device

Tags: uart, rs485, modbus

I have a particle counter HPMA115S0 which has a UART communication interface. I bought a TTL UART to RS485 Converter Module to make it work with a PLC over Modbus RTU protocol.

I usually work with devices that have RS485 serial communication standard but those devices have all the information I need to make them work over a Modbus serial communication protocol (PLC as a master) such as the ID and the baud rate and the registers' addresses which contain the data to request.

However, with HPMA115S0 I don't know what the ID would be, what is the register address of the measurement value and so on. So can I make this device with UART communication to work over Modbus serial protocol by using the UART to RS485 converter?

Comment: Removed my downvote. Thanks for cleaning things up :) I have looked at your fan module's specs. [Here's a fun application and spec sheet](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) for MODBUS. You'll have to go back and forth between the UART specs and MODBUS specs.

Comment: KingDuken Thanks for your reply, how can I get the answer from the Modbus specs?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your device specs, it uses custom UART point-to-point protocol. So it won't be able to process Modbus requests (Modbus frames have a fixed structure: Slave ID, FC, AddrHigh, AddrLow, etc.), no mater what hardware you will use.  So, if you really need to interface this device with Modbus master, you will need to create a Custom-UART/RS485-ModbusRTU gateway that will handle both protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sensor does not need Modbus at all, from the datasheet you can see it uses a simple protocol that sends 32 bytes per frame.

If you have a PLC you should be able to receive these frames quite easily. Most (at least those I've seen) PLCs with an RS485 port can work with either Modbus or what it's called "character mode", which means that the port on the PLC works like a raw UART so to speak, and you have to define your own protocol in your software. When you use this raw protocol you won't need any device address or register number or anything like that you just open your port with the right settings and start listening and processing frames and recording values.

If you don't need a PLC you could always use any kind of computer with a serial port or a USB serial adaptor (RS232 or RS485 if the sensor is far away in the field). The easiest and cheapest I can think of is a Raspberry Pi Zero next to the sensor with a Python script to record values every 10 seconds or more and write them to a database. This way you won't need the RS485 link and you can connect to the Pi to read or download values in many different ways. You can even install something like Domoticz (http://www.domoticz.com/) to have plots with trends or trigger alarms via e-mail or sms (note that I don't think your sensor is supported by Domoticz out of the box, but with such a simple protocol the interface should be a piece of cake).

Many possibilities indeed!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the reason I want to use the rs485 is the distance between the sensor and the PLC and the number of sensors, UART protocol won't work in a great distance and it's a ptp protocol.I bought a TTL to rs485 converter module,I did pull  RE and DE low and I managed to send requests to the sensor and it responds,
but when I switch the pins RE and DE HIGH and the sensor is in auto-send mode I can't receive anything from the sensor

Comment: you're welcome. I see that now you're facing another issue. How are you doing your TTL to RS485 conversion? If you have your own chip (MAX485 or similar) you'll have to drive the DE/~RE signal yourself somehow. If you have an off-the-shelf device it should be able to automatically drive this signal itself. If not, maybe you can do it with a 555 timer as I suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957314/rs485-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device/56066933#56066933

Comment: Reading your comment again I tent to think you're switching the RE/~DE signal manually; if that's the case take a good look at the 555 solution, it's quite easy

Comment: I'm using this rs485 module https://hobbycomponents.com/wired-wireless/663-max485-rs485-transceiver-module

yeah, I did switch it manually to receive from the sensor because the sensor is on auto-send mode it sends data automatically without a request so I think I should to be able to receive something without driving the DE and RE pins?

Comment: I have a couple of those too! I don't see in the spec how fast your sensor will be trying to answer after it receives a query but in general, this time is on the order of milliseconds so I don't think you'll be able to switch the DE/~RE low quickly enough and besides, that would be fine only for testing but once you deploy your sensor somewhere you'll want it to handle the data exchange automatically. As I see it, it doesn't matter that the sensor is in auto-send, you have to switch the DE/~RE signal yourself somehow. Do take a look at the 555 circuit.

Comment: Or if that is too crude for you, maybe take a look at these: https://www.amazon.com/Conversion-Multi-machine-Communication-Ultra-long-distance-Transmission/dp/B078N19X3L   https://www.electronicdesign.com/embedded-revolution/how-create-automatic-direction-control-rs-485-interfaces

Comment: And this is from DSD, I don't have this particular board but the brand is quite ok and the MAX13487 would solve your problem: https://www.amazon.com/DSD-TECH-SH-U12-MAX13487-Raspberry/dp/B07B667STP/ref=pd_cp_23_3?pd_rd_w=p2eEc&pf_rd_p=ef4dc990-a9ca-4945-ae0b-f8d549198ed6&pf_rd_r=TY7E5437388ZT6KVZYY8&pd_rd_r=fea519fc-7978-11e9-b1ee-5b598291dad5&pd_rd_wg=dytDJ&pd_rd_i=B07B667STP&psc=1&refRID=TY7E5437388ZT6KVZYY8    https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/transceivers/MAX13487E.html

Comment: I now see I misunderstood what you meant. The auto-send means you want to keep the bus simplex instead of half duplex. Your sensors will be sending continuously and you'll only read from the PLC or computer. That should work if you keep DE and ~RE always high; the sensor will see echos of its own dataframes but that should not be a problem. I'm keeping the comments above just in case you want to take a look. Note that with the half-duplex you'd be able to change the configuration of the sensor if you need to.

Comment: Thanks again, 
what I don't understand is why I don't receive anything when the sensor on auto-send mode and DE and RE of the module pulled High, because in the real application I only want to receive from the sensor that's all and the sensor is continually sending data, 

I tested the sensor with max232 and I managed to get the data in my pc without sending any request because the sensor is sending continuously,

Comment: Reading the manual I see you only have to send  HEX 68 01 40 57, it will respond with a positive or negative ACK and start sending data immediately. If it works on the TTL side it should work on the RS485 side too as long as you have high on DE and ~RE (actually I don't even think ~RE matters and what I wrote above about the echos is wrong if you keep ~RE high)

Comment: Do you have a scope to check if the signal is getting to the RS485 side? Or maybe another converter to check that the one you're using is not bad

Comment: Ah, now I see something else: your sensor UART gives 3.3V but the transceiver you have is for 5V signals, you might have a problem there. Sometimes you manage to make these 5V decides with 3.3V but it's not sure at all, and not very reliable. See here for a quick trick: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81580/step-up-3-3v-to-5v-for-digital-i-o

Comment: I did test another module and the sem problem, in the max485 datasheet min VIH = 2.0v so 3.3v should work fine.
what I didn't test yet is a logic level converter, I made one by two npn transistors but It didn't work

Comment: You're right about the VIH but this 2V is only valid if your supply is 5V. Anyway if you tried with the level shifter and still won't work there must be something else. Other than checking with a scope I cannot think of anything else. I'll let you know if something else comes to mind