# What type of level shifter will work in this circuit

Tags: level-shifting

[image]

This circuit will probably not work. If I understand it correctly, the high valued R2 resistor in this level shifter (Sparkfun BOB-12009) will prevent logic HIGH to show up on the input of the sensor block.

A non-inverting level-shifter is important, otherwise I can not use the built-in SPI of the Raspberry Pi.

My questions are:

1.) In the case I **can not** modify the Sensor Module in any way:
What type of level shifter will work correctly in such case? One built from discrete parts would be preferred. I could learn more from it and I could build it without buying new components.

2.) In the case I **can** freely change all resistor values in the circuit:
Will the following modification solve the problem?

- R1: 10k,
- R2: 2k,
- R3: 5k,
- R4: 10k

Comment: You can just add an external resister (low value, you can do the math) to be paralleled with R2.

Comment: @Mohammed - Interesting idea. But without increasing the values of R3 and R4 I need to reduce R2 to a very low value. In the case of logic LOW that high current will flow through the Raspberry Pi. With SPI-CLK, SPI-MOSI, SPI-ChSEL will it be not to much for the Raspi?

Comment: If the parallel resetors is 500 the current will be around 10m.

Comment: How discrete is discrete? If you use an op-amp, you can make a filtering, shifting Schmitt Trigger; see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543407/stepping-up-three-3v3-outputs-to-5v/543547#543547 . That targets a specific bitrate, and since yours will be different, the RC time constant will also need to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by the look of your circuit, you don't need to use a bi-directional level shifter for MOSI and SCL so, ditch the bi-directional level shifter and use a TTL-input-level-compatible CMOS buffer fed from a 5 volt supply. Now, SCL and MOSI will be 5 volt line voltages: -

[image]

> *One built from discrete parts would be preferred. I could learn more
> from it and I could build it without buying new components.*

Well, you could build one yourself but, with the loading of R3 and R4, you would need to make the pull-up resistor about 500 ohms: -

[image]

The above is an inverting level shifter so, to make it non-inverting, drive the gate via a compatible inverter buffer (plenty to choose from) but, then again, you might just as well ditch that idea completely and use the SN74LV1T34 (or a compatible device).

Alternatively you could do this: -

[image]

This means adding a local SN74LV1T34 (or a compatible device) in the sensor block area and swapping the 3.3 volt logic drives to feed sensor B directly.

Comment: The recommended SN74LV1T34 seems to be a very useful device. I added it to my shopping list. Thank you.

Comment: @mTThomas you can probably get hold of alternatives that may come with multiple devices in one package.

Comment: The ‘LV1T34 has a lower output resistance Vol (@ 5V) /8mA = Rol=300mV max = 37.5 ohms and Roh=(Vdd-Voh)/8mA = 50 ohms , you would need a Low Vgs(th) =1V FET to support Vdd=1.8V for DIY and drive it source with common gate bias ~ <1V to emulate this. With Rout = drivers 22 ohms /w RdsOn=15 ohm approx

Comment: @Andy aka: To your last schematic: So if I prepend each sensor (A and B) with a dedicated buffer similar to the mentioned SN74LV1T34 and connect the inputs of the buffers then I will get a more universally usable sensor block that can be freely driven from 3.3V and 5.0V logic without an external level-shifter?

Comment: Yes @mTThomas if each buffer is locally fed from the logic rail of the sensor it is servicing.